# Microsoft Edge does not open/read online PDFs

Tags: pdf, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I recently upgrade from Windows 8.1 Pro N to Windows 10 Pro N and I immediately notice a lot of problems. First one: Microsoft Edge does not open/read online PDFs.

If I want to open an online PDF, like a scientific paper or a programming manual, I receive this message from Edge: "*Something is missing. To view a PDF, you need some media functionality that you don't current have. You can install the Media Feature Pack to view this PDF*".

I understand that Windows N needs some additional tools, so I installed the [Media Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48231), as MS Edge suggests me, but the problem still remains and I cannot open any PDF.

I admit that I don't know what to do and I'm not able to find useful information on the web.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably if you specify what "…does not open…" [_actually_ means](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask), it is easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry but I thought I was clear. If I want to open an online PDF, like a scientific paper or a programming manual, I receive this message from Edge: "_Something is missing. To view a PDF, you need some media functionality that you don't current have. You can install the Media Feature Pack to view this PDF_".

Comment: @MarcoCarletti - You didn't provide the error in your original revision that is where the confusion was generated from.

Comment: @Ramhound - Sorry, in my mind everything was clear but I forgot to write it down correctly. I hope now my question is more understandable.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're running the release build of Windows 10 (10240) and that you're *not* part of the Windows Insider program?

Comment: @CharlesMorris-MSFT - Yes: Windows 10 Pro N edition, release build 10.0.10240. I'm not part of the Windows Insider program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem -and thought I had gone through the correct process and downloaded the correct version of the Media Feature Pack (I have a 32 bit OS on  an x64 so downloaded Windows10-KB3010081-x64). It seemed to install, but to no effect. After much searching (and having come across your question) I then read a comment that the other download Windows10-KB3010081-x86 was associated with the 32bit version so I downloaded and installed that - lo and behold I now have the expected "pdfs displaying in edge" and associated behaviour. It would have helped if there was better guidance on the download page as to which to download - or at least some automated checking as part of the instillation process. Ho hum.
Good luck  Simon

Comment: Thanks! One month ago I tried to install the MFP-x64 but I got an "architecture error", so the installation failed. The installation of the x86 version did not change anything. After your suggestion, I retried the same thing (without hope, I admit) but the installation was successful. After the installation of the Windows10-KB3010081-x64 MS Edge shows me online PDFs :)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same trouble, I went to the 3 dots top right of edge tool bar then clicked on open in windows explorer. success

Answer (score 0):

Please download the media feature pack, it works. http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=48231

Comment: As I said to Simon, I got an "architecture error" during the installation of the MFP-x64 and the x86 version did not change anything. So the MFP did _not_ work, at the time I wrote the question. Maybe some update of MS Edge, MFP or OS fixed something. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to get Microsoft Edge to open pdfs:-
Open Internet Explorer
Click on down arrow against pdf logo at top right
Click on 'Convert web page to pdf'
Done

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand... Why I need to open IE? How IE can modify Edge functionalities? In any case, If I open a page like [THIS](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/glm-0.9.6.pdf) in IE, the PDF is shown correctly _in the browser_, while in Edge I see a white page with the message I wrote in the question. The problem is not to download a PDF (if there is a link), but only in the browser visualization.